# Manipulando com Update Panel

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, vb.net

Estou trabalhando com `asp:button e asp:Listbox` utilizando o evento do `click` do `asp:button` para popular os listbox. Estou tentando gerenciar para que não ocorra mais postBack no evento do `click` do botão, porém da forma como estou implementando não está surtindo efeito com o `updatePanel`, gostaria de uma colaboração para poder sanar e aprender com o caso. O código segue abaixo:

HTML:

```
<%@ Register Src="../Modelos/Cabecalho.ascx" TagName="Cabecalho" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Lysis</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Tratamento com o UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updProcesso" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updProcesso" runat="server" >--%>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Campos Disponíveis
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ListBox ID="lstOrigem" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                                Width="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAcima" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mover para Cima"
                                Width="110px" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAbaixo" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mover para Baixo"
                                Width="110px" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSelecionar" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Selecionar"
                                Width="110px" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDesfazer" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Desfazer Seleção"
                                Width="110px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Campos Selecionados
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Ordem
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Operação
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ListBox ID="lstDestino" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                                Width="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ListBox ID="lstOrdem" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                                Width="50px"></asp:ListBox>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnMudaOrdem" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mudar Ordem"
                                Width="95px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ListBox ID="lstOperacao" CssClass="DropDownlist" runat="server" Height="200px"
                                Width="115px"></asp:ListBox>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnMudaOperacao" CssClass="Botao" runat="server" Text="Mudar Operação"
                                Width="110px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Exemplo do tratamento de um Button:

```
Protected Sub btnSelecionar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelecionar.Click

        Try

            ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(CType(sender, Control))

            If lstOrigem.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

                If lstOrigem.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

                    For item As Integer = lstOrigem.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

                        If lstOrigem.Items(item).Selected Then

                            Dim origem As New ListItem
                            origem.Text = "----"
                            origem.Value = lstOrigem.SelectedItem.Value

                            lstDestino.Items.Add(lstOrigem.SelectedItem)
                            lstOrdem.Items.Add(origem)

                            Dim operacao As New ListItem
                            operacao.Text = "----"
                            operacao.Value = lstOrigem.SelectedItem.Value

                            lstOperacao.Items.Add(operacao)
                            lstOrigem.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrigem.SelectedIndex)
                            lstDestino.ClearSelection()

                        End If

                    Next

                End If

                btnSelecionar.Focus()
                updProcesso.Update()

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            Session("erro") = ex
            Response.Redirect("../Paginas/Erro.aspx")

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Venho aqui informar que eu resolvi tratando a proprieadade <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>

Answer (score 1):

Dentro desse cenário eu não saberia como trabalhar, entretanto poderiamos abordar de uma maneira diferente.

Crie uma div com `runat=server`, dessa forma, no `onload` da página voce consegue oculta-la via `codebehind`, ou se voce preferir, pode não utilizar o `runat=server` na tag e oculta-la via jQuery.

Então voce poderia criar uma variavel global que guardaria o status de `bind` dos dados. Ela iniciaria em `false`, e após o primeiro `bind` das informações ocorrerem, ela seria setada para `true`.

Sempre que clicar no botão para carregar as informações, antes de carregar ele faz um check da variavel que quarda o status do `bind`, e só carrega se o status dela for `false`, sendo assim, ela só carregaria uma unica vez, pois ao fim do primeiro carregamento ela seria setada para `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer esse tratamento via javascript o código abaixo é um exemplo de como evitar um novo postback(ajax) do mesmo "objeto" antes que o atual termine.

Inserir após o `form` `runat="server"`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var control_ = null, inst_ = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { 
         control_ = args.get_postBackElement();  //Controle que disparou o PostBack 
         control_.disabled = true; //Desabilita o controle
    } 
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) { 
         control_.disabled = false; //habilita o controle
         control_ = null; 
    }
    inst_.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler); //início da requisição
    inst_.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); //fim da requisição
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma Trigger no botão, um exemplo abaixo de um problema que resolvi com esse recurso por causa do postback:

Veja no exemplo que Trigger dentro do UpdatePanel, essa trigger está referenciando meu botão para disparar a ação Onclick.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="fl_upload" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fl_arquivos" CssClass="btn btn-primary" AllowMultiple="true"/>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-1">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_upload" OnClick="btn_upload_Click" Text="Enviar" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>
                                    </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_upload" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Depois que eu clicar no meu botão, chamo a ação do meu botão :

```
protected void btn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //AÇÃO DO MEU BOTÃO
            //E para finalizar atualizo o UpdatePanel
            fl_upload.Update();

}
```

Comment: Fiz as adaptações como orientado, porém o postback continua a acontecer. O fato de minha ação do botão é popular as listbox não afetaria no funcionamento do UpdatePanel?